# OCaml 5.0.0~beta1: How to use an argument of Effect when their effect handler is not specified (Using Unhandled Exception)

Tags: exception, ocaml, type-safety, ocaml-5

I am using opam switch: 5.0.0~beta1

I was playing around with some simple functions (on utop):

```
type _ Effect.t += Foo : (unit -> unit) -> unit Effect.t
let a = try perform (Foo (fun () -> Printf.printf "Hello from Foo\n ")) with
| Unhandled (Foo f) -> f ();;
Output: Hello from Foo
 val a: unit = ()
```

This works well.
But when we change the definition of Foo effect,

```
type _ Effect.t += Foo : ('a -> unit) -> unit Effect.t
let a = try perform (Foo (fun n -> Printf.printf "Hello from Foo\n ")) with
| Unhandled (Foo f) -> f 45;;
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         $Foo_'a
```

Here I understand that it needs `'a` as an input, but while calling the function, shouldnt it infer the type as `int` and replace `'a` with `int` and execute the function accordingly?  I want to call function `f` from `Foo effect` with different argument.

Here is the another example:

```
 type _ Effect.t += Suspend : 'a -> unit Effect.t
let a = try perform (Suspend 32) with
| Unhandled (Suspend x) -> x;;
Error: This expression has type $Suspend_'a
       but an expression was expected of type $Unhandled_'a
```

Here, I understand that return value of (`try _ with`) i.e. (`unit`) should be the type of `$Unhandled_ 'a`.
But I also want to know, what is `$Unhandled_ 'a` type? How is normal `'a` is different from `$Unhandled_ 'a`? How to return `$Unhandled_ 'a` here? Why there is this special use of `$Unhandled`?
What will be its scope (In some examples where I was using following code,

```
type _ Effect.t += Foo : ('a -> unit) -> unit Effect.t
 let p = try Lwt.return (some_function x) with
                | Unhandled (Foo f) -> let (pr, res) = Lwt.task () in 
                    let wkup v = (Lwt.wakeup res v; ()) in
                        f wkup;
                    pr
```

I also got error as :

```
    This expression has type $Unhandled_'a Lwt.t
        but an expression was expected of type 'a Lwt.t
        The type constructor $Unhandled_'a would escape its scope
```

)?
Why there is

```
        The type constructor $Unhandled_'a would escape its scope
```

error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect part is a red-herring here, the root issue stems from the notion of existentially-quantified types in GADTs.

When you have a GADT which is defined as

```ml
type t = Foo : ('a -> unit) -> t
```

the type of `Foo` means that you can construct a `t` for any type `'a` and any function of type `'a -> unit`. For instance:

```
let l = [Foo ignore; Foo print_int]
```

However, once you have constructed such value, you can no longer knows which type was used to construct the value. If you have a value

```
let test (Foo f) = ...
```

you only know that there exists some type `'a` such that `f` has type `'a -> unit`. This why the type `'a` is called an existentially type (aka a type such that we only know that it exists). The important things to remember is that you don't know which `'a`.  Consequently you cannot apply the function because applying to the wrong `'a` would be a type error.

In other words, the function boxed in `Foo f` can never be called on any value.
This is slightly more subtle variant than the any type

```ml
type any = Any: 'a -> any
```

where the constructor `Any` takes a value of any type and put it in a black box from which it can never be extracted.

In a way existentially-quantified type variables in a GADT lives in their own world and they cannot escape it. But they can be still be useful if this inner world is large enough. For instance, I can bundle a value with a function that prints that value and then forget the type of this value with:

```
type showable = Showable: {x:'a; print:'a -> unit} -> showable
```

Here, I can call the function `print` on the value `x` because I know that whatever is `'a` it is the same `'a` for both `x` and `print`:

```
let show (Showable {x;print}) = print x
```

Thus I can store few showable values in a list

```
let l = [ Showable(0, print_int), Showable("zero", print_string)]
```

and print them later

```
let () = List.iter show l
```